# Density measurement with two components (one solid and one liquid)

Tags: solid-state-physics, mass, density, liquid-state

Not sure if this is the right place, but here it goes. I wonder if this formula works for a mixture between a solid and a liquid:

$$P_t = \frac{1}{\frac{X_a}{P_a} + \frac{X_b}{P_b}}$$

This in the context of a slurry, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The **bulk** density $P$ of a slurry is given by:

$$P=\frac{\Sigma X}{\Sigma V}$$

Assuming $X_a$ and $X_b$ are *mass fractions*, so that $X_a+X_b=1$, then:

$$V_a=\frac{X_a}{P_a}\text{ and }V_b=\frac{X_b}{P_b}$$

So that:

$$\boxed{P=\frac{1}{\frac{X_a}{P_a}+\frac{X_b}{P_b}}}$$

Note that this is a calculation, *not a measurement*.